# How can I add pattern color on single character Android

Tags: android, textview, character

I am wordering that, how can I assign multiple colors on single character as shown below:[image: Urdu character Bay]

This is the character of urdu language.

R&D:
Found that I can [assign multiple colors on different characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074428/how-can-i-set-each-character-to-a-different-color-background-color-in-a-jtextpan), but unable to apply different color patterns on single character.

Comment: http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/14 you can try make a pattern from bitmap

Comment: allow me to check by applying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting solution for others help!

Xml layout Code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPatternCharacter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ب"
    android:textSize="370sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Activity code:

```
 TextView tvPatternCharacter=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPatternCharacter);
        tvPatternCharacter.setText("ب");
 Bitmap bitmap
                = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(),
                R.drawable.pattern);
        Shader shader = new BitmapShader(
                bitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        tvPatternCharacter.getPaint().setShader(shader);
```

Thanks for the link aelimill, [text pattern](http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/14)